# htaccess : redirect user who use ip address to connect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I need to install a second web application site on a web server and hide the fact that's the same server to user.

So far, I have a web app XYZ that you can access via XYZ.com and which is located on the server somewhere like /var/www/
I need to add another webapp ABC which is located /var/www/abc/ and only permit access to people using the ip address.

i.e :

```
www.XYZ.com  --> XYZ ( /var/www/ )
1.2.4.199 --> ABC ( /var/www/abc )
```

I've absolutely no clue how to do that with htaccess. Any help is more than welcomed !

Cheers

Comment: I forget that I would like the final url of the ABC web app to be 1.2.4.199/ NOT 1.2.4.199/abc/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a htaccess thing, more of a vhost setup thing.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: After talking with the tech guy at my provider, it's the way we will go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Place a .htaccess in /var/www/abc

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.2.4.199

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.XYZ.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

This should give visitors to www.XYZ.com a 404 (Not found) when
they try to access http://www.XYZ.com/abc (R=404 is undocumented
but should work)

(note untested, but you get the idea)

Comment: Ryaner has the correct answer, mine was based on that he wanted to protect the /abc/ folder and that VirtualHosting was already setup.
My use of 404 as error is to hide the fact that there are a /abc/ folder.